# Why is Chrome dev tools showing click Event Listeners that aren't bound to my element?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm developing an application which uses:

- jquery 3.2.1
- Bootstrap 3.3.7
- FontAwesome 5.0.8

I have a modal window (with the ID `#notifierModal`) which features an element representing a "down" arrow (using FontAwesome's [chevron-circle-down](https://fontawesome.com/icons/chevron-circle-down?style=solid&from=io)).

The markup for this is as follows:

```
<ul class="fa-ul toggle-notifier-group">
    <li> 
        <a href="#">Item 1</a>
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down toggle-filters"></i>
        <ul class="filters" style="display: none;">
            <li>Item 1 - sub A</li>
            <li>Item 1 - sub B</li>
            <li>Item 1 - sub C</li> 
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li> 
        <a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down toggle-filters"></i>
        <ul class="filters" style="display: none;">
            <li>Item 2 - sub A</li>
            <li>Item 2 - sub B</li>
            <li>Item 2 - sub C</li> 
        </ul>
    </li>

    <!-- Further items -->
</ul>
```

The intention is that when the user clicks on the FontAwesome down arrow it toggles the visibility of the appropriate `.filters` list below (i.e. if the user clicks it for "Item 1", it toggles just the "Item 1 - sub" list).

So I added the following to a file called `app.js` which my application references:

```
$(function() {
    $('#notifierModal').on('click', '.toggle-filters', function () {
        $(this).siblings(".filters").toggle();
    });
});
```

This works but after a few times of using it nothing seems to be happening when the user clicks the icon.

In order to try and debug this I Inspected the `.toggle-filters` elements in Chrome and then went to *Event Listeners > click*. I get the following:

[image]

The reference on line 755 of `app.js` does contain the js I posted above that targets clicks on `.toggle-filters`. But all of the other line numbers are js that has nothing to do with that element. For example:

- Line 201:
  `$(document).on('click', '#exportExcel', function (e) {`
- Line 321: `$(document).on('click', '.browse-ctp__filters-data .include, .browse-ctp__filters-data .exclude', function () {`

All of the other lines (apart from line 755) are like this.

Why is Chrome showing me these if they are not related to the element I'm inspecting and asking to see the click event listeners for? How can I debug this when it's giving me references to stuff that's not related? Or is it related, and is that the point of why it's possibly not working?

Noticed in Chrome version 70.0.3538.77 but have seen this behaviour before in other versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated answer:

That eventListener tab in the side panel of elements tab in the Inspector tool shows the event registered in the page.

> *Why is Chrome showing me these if they are not related to the element I'm inspecting and asking to see the click event listeners for?*

If you select any element in the markup in the elements panel then you can see all the events registered for that element and all the events bound on the parent elements.

> *How can I debug this when it's giving me references to stuff that's not related?*

If you toggle the checkbox then you can see events only bound on the selected element.

Comment: Would that make any difference to what Chrome shows in the *Event Listeners > click* panel? I've added that code but it still shows the same lines of `app.js`

Comment: @Andy okay. i got it now. If you could see. there is a checkbox. It can show you events bound on ancestors as well as on the currently selected element in the elements tab. if you toggle the checkbox it would show you all the events bound on the element and the child events as well.

Comment: If I uncheck "Ancestors" it removes everything from the panel and doesn't show anything at all - everything on the screenshot disappears so it just leaves a white empty space.

Comment: That is good. In this way you can see how the event would get propagated in the dom tree.

Answer (score 0):

this is because of the event propagation. When you click an element the event is propagated to the clicked element to its parent 'till the root of the dom.
If you want to stop the event propagation you can call e.stopPropagation() in you callback function.

```
$('#notifierModal').on('click', '.toggle-filters', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    ...
});
```

[Here](https://www.sitepoint.com/event-bubbling-javascript/) you can have a more detailed explanation